# Is there a way to perform a command line screenshot in Redhat without any GUI involved?

Tags: command-line, screenshot, redhat

I want to be able to take screenshots in Redhat with no GUI involved.  I don't have ImageMagic, so I can't use import (which would be perfect).  I want to write a script which takes a screenshot every so often without user intervention.

I've tried gnome-panel-screenshot, but it brings up the snapshot GUI.

The script would look something like this (pseudo code):

```
sleep_time = <mySleepTime>
filename = <myFilename>
set i = 1
while true do
  filename = filename + "$i"
  <snapshot command> filename
  sleep $sleep_time 
  i = i + 1
end while
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the import command

```
$ import -window root -resize 400x300 -delay 200 screenshot.png
```

It only needs X server running, it won't bring up any interface.

Or using python3 + OpenCV

```
$ pip3 install python3_xlib python-xlib 
$ pip3 install pillow imutils 
$ pip3 install opencv-python
```

$ cat screen.py

```
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import imutils
import cv2

image = pyautogui.screenshot()
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("in_memory_to_disk.png", image)
```

$ python3 screen.py

[image]

It doesn't bring any interface, the script just run and exit

Comment: I tried that as well.  Unfortunately the package with the import command is not installed on our linux (or aix) boxes.  It appears to be a fairly standard linux command.  I'll ask our sys admins why it's not installed.

Comment: I forgot that I mentioned in the original post that I can't use the import command because ImageMagic is not installed on our boxes.  I'll see if the SAs will install it but, if it costs anything, that will require an act of congress.  So, I'm still open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you pip install some dependencies? you could use a virtualenv even :)